# Returning a matrix with constant values in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

How can I return a 2d array of constant values from a function?
I need to return something like this:

```
//I don't even know if this is the best way to do 2d arrays in c++.
const int matrix[4][2] = {
    {10,11},
    {12,13},
    {14,15},
    {16,17}
};
```

Here what i tried:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int** createMatrix();

int main(){
    int **m = createMatrix();
    return 0;
}

const int** createMatrix(){
    const int **matrix = new const int*[4];

    matrix[0] = new const int[2] = {10,11};
    matrix[1] = new const int[2] = {12,13};
    matrix[2] = new const int[2] = {14,15};
    matrix[3] = new const int[2] = {16,17};

    return matrix;
}
```

The output i got:

> main.cpp: In function ‘const int** createMatrix()’:
>   main.cpp:12:13: error: ambiguating new declaration of ‘const int** createMatrix()’
>    const int** createMatrix(){
>                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> main.cpp:5:7: note: old declaration ‘int** createMatrix()’
>    int** createMatrix();
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> main.cpp:15:29: error: uninitialized const in ‘new’ of ‘const int’
>     matrix[0] = new const int[2] = {10,11};
>                                ^
>
> main.cpp:16:29: error: uninitialized const in ‘new’ of ‘const int’
>     matrix[1] = new const int[2] = {12,13};
>                                ^
>
> main.cpp:17:29: error: uninitialized const in ‘new’ of ‘const int’
>     matrix[2] = new const int[2] = {14,15};
>                                ^
>
> main.cpp:18:29: error: uninitialized const in ‘new’ of ‘const int’
>     matrix[3] = new const int[2] = {16,17};

Comment: The function has two different types iint** createMatrix();
 and const int** createMatrix(){

Comment: What exactly is the point of an array of constant values anyway? Each call creates a new copy of the array, so who cares if one caller changed his copy? That doesn't affect other callers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function declaration and the function definition have different return types.

```
int** createMatrix();
```

and

```
const int** createMatrix(){
```

Also such an initialization like this

```
matrix[0] = new const int[2] = {10,11};
```

is incorrect.

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <iostream>

const int** createMatrix();

int main()
{
    const int **m = createMatrix();
    return 0;
}

const int ** createMatrix()
{
    const int **matrix = new const int*[4];

    matrix[0] = new const int[2] {10,11};
    matrix[1] = new const int[2] {12,13};
    matrix[2] = new const int[2] {14,15};
    matrix[3] = new const int[2] {16,17};

    return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution, is to make an array of arrays, like you show first, and return that.

Make it `static` inside the function so its lifetime will not end. And remember to return the correct type (an array of arrays is not the same as a pointer to a pointer).

Optionally use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of plain C-style arrays.

If the size is configurable at run-time then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider saving it as a 1d array of length (xsize*ysize) this is, allegedly, better than saving 2d arrays.